# QGIS 2.6 Atlas creator - number of copies of output based on field

Tags: qgis, atlas

I am using QGIS 2.6 to create a series of maps based on a coverage grid. For each grid, I have a field named COUNT, that determines the number of copies I'd like to output. Is there any way to automatically set this up using the the atlas creator?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is currently possible. A workaround could be to create as many copies of the same feature in the coverage layer as you need to reach the COUNT value.

Comment: Is this done manually, then? I'm not sure what you mean by "create as many copies"?

Comment: Yes, that would be manually or at least in a separate step. It would be easy to automate with a pyqgis script.